# Sum of random variables that are pareto-distributed

Tags: probability-distributions

If we have $X_1, X_2, ..., X_k$ where all X's are pareto-distributed, what is the distribution of $X_1+...+X_k$?
And what is the distribution of $a\cdot X_1$ if $X_1$ is pareto-distributed.

Comment: Without independence the question has no meaning.

Comment: So lets assume they are independent

Comment: Is there no one that can answer?